# How to change Swift structures properties order?

Tags: swift, struct, dump

I have structure in my case it is `User`.

Example structure with properties (For example purposes, it has only a few properties).

```
struct User {
   var name:String?
   var email:String?
}
```

Now I am creating `User` struct with specific order (email, name) of the fields.

```
var user = User()
user.email = "Oleg@gmail.com"
user.name = "Oleg"
```

And now I am doing `dump` of the structure to see properties order.

```
dump(user)

▿ __lldb_expr_21.User
  ▿ name: Optional("Oleg")
    - some: "Oleg"
  ▿ email: Optional("Oleg@gmail.com")
    - some: "Oleg@gmail.com"
```

**So is it possible to change structures properties order to be in the same order that I added them? Or should i use Array to save properties order?**

Expected result of `dump` is:

```
▿ __lldb_expr_25.User
  ▿ email: Optional("Oleg@gmail.com")
    - some: "Oleg@gmail.com"
  ▿ name: Optional("Oleg")
    - some: "Oleg"
```

Comment: `User` has two *properties,* and it does not matter in which order you assign values to them. Why should it? – Also `dump()` is for *debugging* and you should not rely on the specific order in which it prints the properties.

Comment: @MartinR user struct has more than 20 properties in real project. I have issue with legacy project when it is required to be able to log sequence of the properties of the structure in the way that I describe.

Comment: Why is the order important? The order will be the order as defined in the definition of the struct. If, for some reason, you need to maintain the order that properties were set for each instance of the struct, then you could add a suitable array and some property observers to save the order.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Does it really make sense to have a User without a name or e-mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory layout algorithm of structs is not yet concretely decided. It's tracked in [SR-3723](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3723). It may very well change in the future, for a variety of reasons:

- members could be more tightly packed, if the compiler is not constrained to preserving the order, resulting in less memory wasted in padding for meeting alignment constraints
- members could be close packed for better locality (thus better cache performance) for commonly used operations

The point is, you should absolutely isolate yourself from the memory layout of structs. Their layout can change in any future version of Swift, and you don't want that to break your program.

From the comments, your issue seems to have absolutely nothing to do with the memory layout of structs, but rather the way their variables appear when you log them. This is something you can define yourself:

```
struct User {
   let name: String
   let email: String
}

extension User: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "your custom description"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexnder great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a terrible idea, you can modify the output of `dump` by adding a custom `Mirror`:

```
extension User : CustomReflectable {
    var customMirror: Mirror {
        let children = DictionaryLiteral<String, Any>(
            dictionaryLiteral: ("email", self.email as Any), ("name", self.name as Any)
        )

        return Mirror(User.self, children: children)
    }
}
```

`dump` is meant for debugging and the order of properties in debugging output should not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I would expect the dump to be in the same format as your struct

```
struct User {
    var name:String?
    var email:String?
}

//Dump
~Name
~Email
```